# According to what rule is it 'the Bolsheviks' and not just 'Bolsheviks' (even when not talking about specific people)?

Tags: grammar, articles

If it was 'the Bolshevik', it would be understandable ('Used to make a generalized reference to something rather than identifying a particular instance,' the third sense here: https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/the). And yet, it's plural. The similar goes for names of nationalities. Most examples in the Lexico entry for 'Russian' that use the plural form go with 'the' (https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/russian). Some, on the other hand, do not (for instance, 'It was Russians who first built up a caviar industry on Iranian shores.'). Please explain.

Comment: for starters, please see John Lawler on generic noun phrases: http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/000001.html

Comment: I don't see how it can help me with my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we talk about all members of specific group of people collectively - for example, a team, a family, the people of a nation, a political party, we use **the**.

> [**The Lions** are a South African professional rugby union team from Johannesburg who compete in the Super Rugby competition](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lions_(Super_Rugby)).
>
> [Keeping up with **the Kardashians**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keeping_Up_with_the_Kardashians)
>
> [How did **the Germans** get that way](https://www.historians.org/about-aha-and-membership/aha-history-and-archives/gi-roundtable-series/pamphlets/em-26-can-the-germans-be-re-educated-(1945)/how-did-the-germans-get-that-way)?
>
> [The Conservative Party, officially the Conservative and Unionist Party and also known colloquially as **the Tories** or simply **the Conservatives**, is a centre-right political party in the United Kingdom.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_Party_(UK))

**[The Bolsheviks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolsheviks)** were a political party, so when we talk about them collectively, we use **the**.

If you are talking about all Russians collectively, or a small group of them acting on behalf of the whole, for example a sporting team who represent Russia, an army, or the Russian government, you refer to them as "the Russians".

> [Why Were **the Russians** So Set Against This Hacker Being Extradited](https://krebsonsecurity.com/2019/11/why-were-the-russians-so-set-against-this-hacker-being-extradited/)

If you are talking about a small group of people, who happen to be Russian but are not are not acting on behalf of the whole, you refer to them as "Russians".

> It was **Russians** who first built up a caviar industry on Iranian shores - *q.v. OP's question*

Note that, sometimes in news headlines, articles are omitted: this is called [journalese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journalese).

> [Hillary Clinton suggests **Russians** are 'grooming' Tulsi Gabbard for third-party run](https://edition.cnn.com/2019/10/18/politics/hillary-clinton-tulsi-gabbard/index.html)

When the same sentence is repeated in the body of the article, **the Russians** is used.

> Former Democratic presidential nominee Hillary Clinton said Thursday **the Russians** are currently "grooming" a Democrat running in the presidential primary to run as a third-party candidate and champion their interests.

Comment: Why is it 'Russians' in one sentence and 'the Russians' in the other? What's the difference between '[pl. noun]' and 'the [pl. noun]'?

Comment: sorry, I forgot to answer that part of your question. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

When talking about a fully specified group of people or things we can use "the" to mean that fully specified group.

> The lions come down to the waterhole at night
>
> The English enjoy tea
>
> The punks would wear ripped t-shirts.
>
> The Bolshovicks were a political party that gain control of Russia following the October revolution.

And so on.

Comment: There's some vagueness in your answer: 'fully specified' (any group shares some common characteristics) and 'can' (is it optional?)